# How to rewrite native query to JPA criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to rewrite the query on the criteria

```
@Query(value = "select count(*), hicn.name \n" +
                "from \n" +
                "  table1 cid, \n" +
                "  table2 hicn \n" +
                "where TRUNC(cid.CREATED_WHEN) = TRUNC(?) \n" +
                "  and hicn.ID = cid.ID\n" +
                "group by  hicn.name", nativeQuery = true)
```

and put result in the DTO?

```
public class DataDto {
    private String name;
    private Long count;

    public DataDto(String name, Long count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Entity for example.Entity large, reduced for convenience. Can you show the solution with 'join' and 'and'. The main problem is that I don't understand how to access two tables and get data from them using criteria.

For table 1

```
 @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TABLE_ONE")
    public class TableOneModel {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "TAB_ONE_ID")
        private Long tabOneId;

        @Column(name = "CREATED_WHEN")
        private Date createdWhen;
    }
```

For table 2

```
 @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TABLE_TWO")
    public class TableTwoModel {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "TAB_TWO_ID")
        private Long tabTwoId;

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;
    }
```

Comment: Not a solution. But remove `\n` in query that is not needed

Comment: Show the entities for the tables

Comment: added my entities to question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TableOneModel.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("TableTwoModel", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("trunc(cid.CREATED_WHEN)", "checkpoint"))
                                                  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("name"), "name")
                                                                                             .add(Projections.rowCount(),"Count")
                                                                                             .add(Projections.groupProperty("name"))).uniqueResult();
List list = criteria.list();
```

Your target must be looking something near to this. I didnt test out code though. I was not sure about what to put on your sql **trunc** method, so I added **checkpoint** there. If thats a dynamic variable, please research yourself how you can add it to criteria. In fact that may depend more on your code as well.

Comment: that isn't JPA Criteria. It is Hibernate Criteria. And the question says clearly "JPA Criteria"